# Are there still benefits to use more than one IP address for all server services?

Tags: linux, web-server, ip, email-server

I have one IP address for my nameserver, my web server, mail server, ftp server. I use SNI SSL so that my hosted websites have different SSL certificates behind one IP. I use a centralized firewall to protect UDP, TCP, ICMP traffic.

Are there still benefits to use several IP addresses today?

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is. If you had more than one DNS, FTP, mail, etc... servers you may need additional IPs to distinguish between them. Also, if you had multiple links (for various reasons), it could be required to access those same servers.

Answer (score 0):

Today, many IPs (public IPs if you mean so) are used to balance the traffic dirrectyl on internet.

There are not other priviledges than having many of them to distribute the load. Or to have server availability in case one of connections goes wrong. As providers di-per-se will never give you more than one IP per physical link.

Comment: yeah but I'd argue it's simpler for the clients to think about fewer IPs and have VIPs on your end that can be just as easily load balanced in different ways by your firewall or other network equipment

Comment: Ofcourse, but serving, as major part of providers give you assimetric connection with UPLOAD just 1/10 of DOWNLOAD is really easy to reach the limit. Therefore i can see less sense to use more VIPs as traffic is all trought the same connection for balancement and releability!

Answer (score 0):

In some infrastructures it is beneficial to have a dedicated physical link for ssh. That way you will still be able to access your server when you are the victim of a DDOS attack.

When using virtualization it is quite common to give each virtual host its own IP using bridges which means that one physical interface is in charge of potentially many IPs.